How to fetch data for search filter and pagination in complex application using SSR?
I have a next js 14 application using the app router, with a large number of records, and I need to display the count of elements for each filter option (e.g., categories, tags). It's inefficient to recalculate these counts every time a pagination event occurs ie when URL parameters change.
I want to fetch the filter data (i.e., the counts) separately from the data for the records (posts). This should be done in a way that minimizes redundant calculations and ensures efficient data fetching for each page.
How Would You Solve This?
For some more context, we are working on the premise that you want to render all your pages server side so no fetching clientside. Let’s presume that the backed is optimised fully.
Variant 1 Paralel query for filters count and posts at the backend level lasts a variable amount of time 800-1800ms. Drawback every time you paginate it recalculates the filter parameters which has no point. This works pretty ok up to 100000 records but when you have 20+ filter props and geolocation and autocomplete search going on no matter the paralel sharing it gets lengthy.
Variant 2 Fetch filters count only when filter parameters change So first time rendering you have a long query time, for example. /?category=x&location=y&page=1 You get back the json with categories and counts ex. {Car: 1, Bicicle:5, Boat: 7} same with locations, and of course the posts. The second time when only the page changes you don’t want to calculate the filter parameters which stay the same, ex. /?category=x&location=y&page=2 but since you are SSR you have to fetch again if everything. You could get only the post but then you will have to fetch posts client side and use shallow routing.
One possibility that I thought of was paralel routing one for the filter and one for the posts and using optimistic or swr update the filter at a later time.
